# Creating file via relative path not working with IDE

Tags: java, file, intellij-idea, inputstream

I'm trying to get a grasp of streams and sockets right now so what I wanted to do for an early test is simply read lines from a normal txt-file.

I first set it up via the IntelliJ IDE and the code is as follows,

```
package NixWichtiges;

import java.io.*;

/**
 * Created by Wolfone on 08.03.2017.
 */
public class StreamReadTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("test.txt")));
            String message;
            while ((message = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                bufferedReader.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The test.txt is located in the same folder in which StreamReadTest.java is located and i checked that it is contained in the respective path of the compiled output which is created by doing a **run** in IntelliJ. But i keep getting a `FileNotFoundException`.

I am even more confused by the fact that when I tried it on my other computer just via commandline-comilation and execution it worked just fine (using the default package for this test).

Can someone explain what is going wrong?

Thanks in advance for any input on this.

Best wishes
Wolfone

Comment: Unless you use specific path, the file in context must be in the path from where JVM is invoked.

Comment: idea runs project from the root project directory, so in your case you should change `new File("test.txt")` to `new File("src/main/java/NixWichtiges/test.txt")` or put file to the root project directory

Comment: Ah, ok i thought that it would be something like this Reddy but i didn't think about the possibility that idea would run the whole thing from a different location than the main-containing class i was using, so thanks Slava for your answer on that. Solved my issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with IntelliJ -- you'd have the same problem no matter how you run this app. You have referenced a file with no path, which means that it will be found in the directory from which you started the jvm running the code. Try using an absolute path and this should fix it. Alternatively, learn about classpath-resources, which is the preferred way of locating files. And, even trivial programs like this should be built using maven (which is really easy).

Finally, you shouldn't have this file in your source directory (src/main/java). It should be in a resources directory (src/main/resources).

To confirm which directory you're running in you could create a file and look at its absolute path, with something like:

```
System.out.println(new File("").getAbsolutePath());
```

Comment: Thanks for your input! I don't really know much about Maven, i know a little bit about Ant; from which i understand both are build tools. Sorry for the follow up question but now that you mention it: are there major differences i have to consider when choosing which to use?

Comment: There is no choice. Use maven. There is a third option: Gradle, but again there is no choice: use maven. Maven is really easy to get started with, but you'll have to put up with a little xml to start with (https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Minimal_POM). Put the xml in that link in a file called pom.xml in your project's root, then close your project and delete the .idea folder, then 'open' the pom -- idea will take over from there.

Comment: Ok, seems pretty rigorous to be honest but knowing more different things won't hurt most of the time so thanks for linking :)